# create-react-app npm run build fail to minify watson node sdk

Tags: reactjs, minify, create-react-app, watson

I am new to React and I am trying to build a react app using **create-react-app** and [Watson node-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk). Everything works fine in development mode after running `npm start`. But when I try to build a production package using `npm run build` and below is the error I receive.

```
e:\Microsoft\Workspace\React\myapp>npm run build

> myapp@0.1.0 build e:\Microsoft\Workspace\React\myapp
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

    ./node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/lib/helper.js:31

Read more here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-
20T09_40_36_144Z-debug.log
```

The line that giving error is `let missing;` and seems like the `let` is causing the issue. Is there anything I can do with this?

Comment: Can you please show more of code from the file  ./node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/lib/helper.js ?  which is causing the error?

Comment: here you go.
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/d5909a19d8846a9e7a104242a193b7f54c69c4ca/lib/helper.js#L31

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem today. the doc suggests some solutions:

> 1. Open an issue on the dependency's issue tracker and ask that the package be published pre-compiled.
> 2. Fork the package and publish a corrected version yourself.
> 3. If the dependency is small enough, copy it to your src/ folder and treat it as application code.

Read more here: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify